# Add new migrations from Rails engine gem to app via generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, rails-engines

I'm building a Rails engine in a ruby gem. It includes some migrations right now that are called when you run:

```
rails g myengine:install
```

The code in the generator is as follows:

```
module MyEngine
  module Generators
    class InstallGenerator < ::Rails::Generators::Base
      include Rails::Generators::Migration

      source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

      # ...

      def copy_migrations
        migration_template "migrations/migration1.rb", "db/migrate/migration1.rb"
        migration_template "migrations/migration2.rb", "db/migrate/migration2.rb"
      end

      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

However, if I run `rails g myengine:install` again, it fails with this error:

```
Another migration is already named migration1: /Users/jh/Code/Web/demoapp/db/migrate/20130327222221_migration1.rb
```

I want it to just silently ignore the fact that there's already a migration and continue on to the next migration. **What would be the best way to do this?**

**EDIT:**

Per Dmitry's answer, this was my solution:

```
  def copy_migrations
    copy_migration "migration1"
    copy_migration "migration2"
  end

protected

  def copy_migration(filename)
    if self.class.migration_exists?("db/migrate", "#{filename}")
      say_status("skipped", "Migration #{filename}.rb already exists")
    else
      migration_template "migrations/#{filename}.rb", "db/migrate/#{filename}.rb"
    end
  end
```

Comment: @Mischa, mine do have meaningful names in the real application. That doesn't help when you're re-running the install generator to upgrade it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad you solved it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [migration_template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/migration.rb) in Rails as example, you could perhaps check for `destination = self.class.migration_exists?(migration_dir, @migration_file_name)` and if migration already exists, skip over making `migration_template` call.

Comment: `migration_exists?` worked. Thanks. just to clear. `migration_exists?` takes two string parametrers. `@migration_file_name` is only available inside the template file